# Calling groovy method from script

Tags: groovy, scripting

I'm writing a program in groovy, I want it to run a script with dynamically changing variables. The script is supposed to execute a method with its variables. This method is located in the program that runs the script.

The script would contain something like this:

```
// getAttribute is a method in my main program, the program which also runs the script
value = getValue("java.lang:type=OperatingSystem", "FreePhysicalMemorySize")

// do something with the value
if (value > 9000) { output = "ERROR" }

// the same thing maybe a few more times
value = getValue(...
```

I want to keep it as simple as possible.

I was working with these examples: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy

I already tried to use the GroovyScriptEngine, but it seems like the script only accepts Strings as input values. It would be great if I could hand over method pointers.

Just trying to hand over an integer like this:

```
def roots = 'PATH\\script.groovy'
def groscreng = new GroovyScriptEngine(roots)
def binding = new Binding()
def input  = 42
binding.setVariable("input", input)
groscreng.run("script.groovy", binding)
println binding.getVariable("output")
```

With this script.groovy

```
output = ${input}
```

results in this error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: script.$() is applicable for argument types: (script$_run_closure1) values: [script$_run_closure1@fcf50]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

Receiving the value in the script as a String like "${input}" works just fine.

I know it has to work somehow and I would appreciate any help or other suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = ${input}
```

isn't valid groovy

Try:

```
output = input
```